# playing of bag files never ends

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone
I built two bag files: the first one contains 4000 messages, the second one only one message (it's just needed to advice my program that the first bag file has finished playing).
This is what I get by applying **rosbag info** to first bag

```
ubisum@ubisum:~/fuerte_workspace/beginner/bags$ rosbag info subset.bag
path:        subset.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    3:45s (225s)
start:       Jan 01 1970 01:36:56.10 (2216.10)
end:         Jan 01 1970 01:40:41.30 (2441.30)
size:        20.5 MB
messages:    4507
compression: none [28/28 chunks]
types:       nav_msgs/Odometry     [cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7]
             sensor_msgs/LaserScan [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]
topics:      /base_scan   2254 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan
             /odom        2253 msgs    : nav_msgs/Odometry
```

and to the other one:

```
ubisum@ubisum:~/fuerte_workspace/beginner/bags$ rosbag info end.bag
path:        end.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    0.0s
start:       Dec 19 2012 15:15:20.78 (1355926520.78)
end:         Dec 19 2012 15:15:20.78 (1355926520.78)
size:        4.7 KB
messages:    1
compression: none [1/1 chunks]
types:       std_msgs/String [992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1]
topics:      /end   1 msg     : std_msgs/String
```

When they are played separately, I can see on shell only one row, telling me how many seconds are left before ending of playing and the total duration is exactly the one reported by **rosbag info**.
When I play two bags in sequence by

```
rosbag play subset.bag end.bag
```

during playing of first bag I get the following:

```
  
  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2376.300271   Duration: 160.200271 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2376.400248   Duration: 160.300248 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2376.500284   Duration: 160.400284 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2376.600396   Duration: 160.500396 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2376.701079   Duration: 160.601079 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2376.800272   Duration: 160.700272 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2376.901247   Duration: 160.801247 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2377.000184   Duration: 160.900184 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2377.100197   Duration: 161.000197 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2377.200328   Duration: 161.100328 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2377.301192   Duration: 161.201192 / 1355924304.678373  
   [RUNNING]  Bag Time:   2377.400301   Duration: 161.300301 / 1355924304.678373
```

Anyway, these lines continue to appear on the screen and playing never ends: it goes beyond expected duration and I have to stop it by Ctrl+C.
Do you know the reason?

Thanks for support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50986/playing-of-bag-files-never-ends/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The timestamps on your two bag files are 42 years apart. [It will take that long](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#play) to get from the first set of messages to the second.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-23**:
nice, do I need a Delorean? :)
apart from jokes, timestamp was determined after registration of messages in the bag. How could/should I modify timestamp of bag file to make sequential playing effective?
thanks

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-23**:
The simplest thing at this point is probably to write the second file with a zero timestamp (Jan 1, 1970).

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-23**:
how can I perform this modification?